# Should duktape be able to handle this nested assignment construct?

Tags: javascript, typescript, duktape

I'm using TypeScript to generate enum code that I'm running in a duktape interpreter:

```
var NodeType;
(function (NodeType) {
    NodeType[NodeType["none"] = 0] = "none";
    NodeType[NodeType["text"] = 1] = "text";
})(NodeType || (NodeType = {}));
```

duktape will resolve `NodeType["text"] => 1` but not `NodeType[1] => "text"`. I'm not sure if this is a bug with duktape or just something it doesn't support.

Comment: Well duktape claims to be ES5.1 compliant, and that's perfectly legal JavaScript, so I'd call it  a bug.

Comment: @Pointy Thanks -- filed a issue with the project. https://github.com/svaarala/duktape-wiki/issues/59

Comment: Moved the issue to the Duktape main repo (from the duktape-wiki repo): https://github.com/svaarala/duktape/issues/427. The bug is already fixed in master but exists in Duktape 1.3.0. It's been added to the fix list for 1.3.1.

Answer (score 1):

Was an issue on 1.3.0 that is fixed on master and will be fixed in 1.3.1. I was using 1.3.0.